# PyInstaller used on Ubuntu - compressed file used on CentOS -error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I've python code and I've compressed it with PyInstaller 3.5. My dev. env is an Ubuntu 18.04 server but customer would like to run and use compressed python script on CentOS 7.6

I've got a feedback with error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_certifi.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-16KWaj/PyInstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-16KWaj/PyInstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 684, in load_module
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIhotjJf/libcrypto.so.1.1)
[22972] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_certifi
```

Does it mean that need to compress python code on CentOS 7.6 or is there any other problem?
I've checked compressed code in my dev.environment and it run well...that's the reason why I think that OS difference could couse the error/problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInstaller will only compile for the platform it is executed on. While both CentOS and Ubuntu are Linux distros, it doesn't mean they are built the same way! Some libs present on ubuntu might very well be missing from CentOS.

This theory is even more likely seeing that the compiled binary will run in your ubuntu but not in the CentOS. This, to me, suggests that there is nothing wrong with your compilation (no missing external files or incorrectly compiled dependencies) but that the /usr/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' needed by the program and present on Ubuntu might not be present on CentOS.

Compiling the program on CentOS would most likely result in PyInstaller detecting this missing dependency and adding it to the compiled binary.

The first thing to test is to try running your python script on CentOS and seeing if that raises any errors in the IDE. If it doesn't then your next step is to try compiling directly on CentOS. If the script didn't raise an error then the compilation should work for that OS and so should the compressed output of PyInstaller.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @alex_bits! That was I am affraid...but OK! I am goning to create a CentOS dev env, check what you suggested and compile python script on CentOS. Thanks

Comment: You can easily install a centOS as a virtual machine using VirtualBox! Compilation using PyInstaller works perfectly in VMs. This is what I do when I need to compile for a specific OS

Comment: At the end of day I arrived to create a CentOS system, installed pip and 3rd partys. compressed my code with pyinstaller...result: it is working!!!! :)